# How to send current location to another iPhone user swift?

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mapkit, currentlocation

I want to be able to send my current location to another iPhone user. I can get my current location and continuously update my location to see where I am on the map but how could I send this info to another iPhone user so they can see where i am in real time?

The basic structure of code is:

```
  import UIKit
  import MapKit

  class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myMapView: MKMapView!


let myLocMgr = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    myLocMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    myLocMgr.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    myLocMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
    myLocMgr.delegate = self

}



    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        // get most recient coordinate
        let myCoor = locations[locations.count - 1]

        //get lat & long
        let myLat = myCoor.coordinate.latitude
        let myLong = myCoor.coordinate.longitude
        let myCoor2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: myLat, longitude: myLong)

        //set span
        let myLatDelta = 0.05
        let myLongDelta = 0.05
        let mySpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: myLatDelta, longitudeDelta: myLongDelta)

        let myRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myCoor2D, span: mySpan)

        //center map at this region
        myMapView.setRegion(myRegion, animated: true)

        //add anotation
        let myAnno = MKPointAnnotation()
        myAnno.coordinate = myCoor2D
        myMapView.addAnnotation(myAnno)
    }
```

Comment: Too broad. Basically you are asking how to write Find My Friends.

Comment: You need to post this information to a server and have the other device observe this (if realtime) or just request it when searching. Pretty much Like Find My iPhone